# Debian сразу не стартует, просит нажать Ctrl+D

Tags: linux, debian

Проблема возник после нескольких раз некоректных отключений. При старте системы пишет такое

```
give root password for maintenance 
(or type control-d to continue)
```

После нажатия ctrl+D система нормально запускается, но дело в том, что нужно, чтобы все происходила автоматически, т.к. предназначен он для удаленного использования. Как можно исправить это?

Вывыод команды cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-486 root=UUID=1574feda-1c87-4124-8c82-92f7c65ea60a ro quiet
```

Ошибки при старте:

[image: Ошибки перед стартом]

> ```
> [ ok ] Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd.
> [ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events...done
> [....] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated...[ ???
> spkr' is already registered, aborting...
> done.
> [ ok ] Setting preliminary keymap...done.
> [ ok ] Setting parameters of disc: (none).
> [ ok ] Activating swap...done.
> [....] Checking root filesystem...fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
> /dev/sda1: clean, 120539/376752 files, 794127/1526784 blocks
> done.
> [info] Loading kernel module loop.
> [ ok ] Cleaning up temporary files... /tmp.
> [ ok ] Activating lbm and md swap...done.
> [....] Checking file systems...fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
> fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=ee8d17ee-f799-4ee4-911f-3f2310f3f880'
> fsck died with exit status 8
> failed (code 8).
> [....] File system check failed. A log is being saved in /var/log/fsck/checkfs i
> [FAILt location is writable. Please repair the file system manually. ... failed!
> [....] A maintenance shell will now be started. CONTROL-D will terminate this sh
> [warn] ell and resume system boot. ... (warning).
> Give root password for maintenance
> (or type Control-D to continue):
> ```

Comment: Пароль для пользователя `root` задан?

Comment: вы запускаетесь в single-user mode вместо обычного

Comment: А записей про проблему с файловой системой перед этим нет? Или какие-то инные ошибки?

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе, вывод команды `$ lsb_release -a; cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin lsb_release command not found, а cat /proc/cmdline добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @Arhad Да, задан

Comment: @Etki А как это исправить ?

Comment: приведите информацию, которая предшествует приглашению ввести «root password».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Добавил фото сообщения, где видны ошибки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

судя по содержимому последней из картинок, программа *fsck* не смогла найти раздел с *uuid* `ee8d17ee...`:

> `fsck.ext4: Unable to resolve 'UUID=...'`

---

**почему она вообще его искала?** скорее всего потому, что он упомянут в файле `/etc/fstab` (или в одном из файлов в каталоге `/etc/fstab.d/`, если таковой есть) и последнее (шестое) поле, обозначающее *порядок проверки*, не равно нулю. что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
UUID=ee8d17ee... точка-монтирования тип-фс опции-монтирования частота-создания-дампа порядок-проверки
```

**как быть?** либо исправить это поле на ноль, либо закомментировать эту строку, добавив символ `#` в её начало.

**так что выбрать — исправить шестое поле или закомментировать?** в том случае, если раздел с таким *uuid* не существует, строку имеет смысл именно закомментировать. посмотреть (уже после загрузки) *uuid-ы* всех доступных разделов можно, например, программой *blkid*:

```
$ sudo blkid
```

Comment: Действително. В /etc/fstab перед этим UUID, в шестом поле было два. Обнулив, система запустился без проблем.

Comment: В качестве доп.инфы: blkid может не быть установлен на некоторых системах. Тогда можно использовать команду: ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid

Answer (score 1):

введите рутовый пароль, и выполните fsck. Или поищите как сделать так, что бы fsck при запуске не только проверял, но и исправлял ошибки сразу. Например, как описано тут: http://www.opennet.ru/openforum/vsluhforumID1/51339.html

в 90% случаев это и есть проблема. После аварийного завершения работы запускается проверка файловой системы, которая в случае нахождения ошибок просит ввести пароль рута для того, что бы эти ошибки исправить.

UPD. Хоть на вопрос уже ответили, но довести дело до конца, если бы причина была именно в этом:

> Команда fsck выдает /dev/sda1 is mounted и еще e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting. Фото ошибок перед сообщением добавил в вопрос

**Вариант 1 (простой)**:
 Воспользуйтесь liveCD. 
**Вариант 2** (сложнее, может что-то пойти не так):
Сделайте правку файла

> vi /etc/fstab

либо /dev/sda1 в ro (readonly), либо вовсе закомментируйте.
Потом fsck.
Затем:

> mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /

Comment: Команда fsck выдает /dev/sda1 is mounted и еще e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting. Фото ошибок перед сообщением добавил в вопрос.